# Using jQuery to "highlight" content under cursor

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to write some jQuery code that will highlight the element the cursor is currently hovering over by adding a border around it. Here is the code I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Hover Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("*:not(html, head, body)").hover( function () {
            $(this).css("border", "2px solid purple");
        }, 
        function () {
            $(this).css("border", "none");
        }).click( function () {
            alert($(this).html());
        });
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div>
    <p>This is paragraph one</p>
    <p>This is paragraph two</p>
</div>
<span id="curtag"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is when I hover over something like a paragraph in the example below it also highlights the parent tag in this case the div. Additionally, when I click on the paragraph it gives me the html of the p and then the html of the div, however, I only want the html in the p tag. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add

```
return false;
```

like this

```
$(function() {
    $("*:not(html, head, body)").hover( function () {
            $(this).css("border", "2px solid purple");
    return false;
    }, 
    function () {
            $(this).css("border", "none");
    }).click( function () {
            alert($(this).html());
            return false;
    });
});
```

to stop the mouseOver event from bubbeling to the parent.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That works pretty well the only thing is if say I have it so it highlights the div fist and then move into the paragraph tag the div remains highlighted since I haven't quite stopped hovering over it.

Answer (score 0):

You're being too general in what elements you're allowing to trigger the hover() event. When you say `the element the cursor is currently hovering over`, that refers to several nested elements, which are appropriately all getting borders.

If you're only going to have text in `<p>`s, why not just have them alone trigger the border?

```
$('p').hover(function() { etc.....
```